# Reports of many duplicate copies of local notification all firing at same time in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, ios10

I'm getting reports from my app users of many many copies of the same local notification all firing at the same, correct, time and filling the screen with identical copies of the same message. Nothing in the code base has changed. I did see that iOS 10 created additional optional features introduced at WWDC for `UILocalNotifications`, but I didn't notice any mandatory upgrades. Two questions.

(1) Has anyone else gotten these reports from users?

(2) Any known changes to `UILocalNotifications` that would require updates to existing code?

Comment: have you seen receive the local notification in all device?

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P in two users' iphones. None of us devs have iOS10 beta installed on our phones, so we can't test.

Comment: @helloB In iOS Beta versions, there generally be a lot of bugs in the OS, especially that are related with notifications. I guess this is one of them. So, I think there is nothing for you to worry about.

Comment: @Burak Thanks for the comment, but I would feel better if I knew another dev team had seen similar complaints. We got called out on twitter by our users which isn't a good feeling.

Comment: How many local notifications does it schedule? Just one, or several?